# Does trend suggest server-side web programming model (e.g. ASP.NET) being replaced by JavaScript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

ASP.NET server controls has a few categories, for example, normal ones e.g. TextBox, Button which can be done in HTML/JS; Validation controls: can be done in JS; Login controls: I have seen them implemented in JS. Data bound controls: not sure, but maybe JS can work directly with databases, implementing controls like photo slider.

So in the time span of next 5-10 years, will server-side web programming model fall out of mainstream and be replaced by JS/Ajax that interacts directly with databases?

Comment: What about web services and APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So in the time span of next 5-10 years, will server-side web programming model fall out of mainstream and be replaced by JS/Ajax that interacts directly with databases?

What's going on is the same thing we always do in computer technology (née in nature), try and find an equilibrium. As bandwidth increases and javascript [process time decreases & feature set increases in ECMAscript spec] then more effects will be pushed to the client, but as @BrianBall points out, you have to have somewhere to keep the data, or it was for naught.

There was a time when we relied on the client to do all the work because network latency was crippling, and we called those fat clients. There was a time when we didn't trust the client to keep any data because we couldn't trust the client to be able to process anything, and we call that thin-client.

We are rapidly approaching an equilibrium again where we rely on the server to do the heavy lifting on somethings, to manage the data, to maintain security, and to stream video or send emails. Everything else is migrating for the most part to the client. I don't see us moving back to a really fat-client anytime in the next ten years, altho I do see the browser becoming more central to our app usage. A truly standard platform on which to build any app.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are talking about a database on the users machine, then there will need to be something on the server end to connect to the database (unless you leave your database open to the public internet, which is never a good idea if it can be helped).

It seems that with technology, it is always a pendulum.  Client side has one set of benefits and costs while server side has a different set.  Usually if everything is heavy on the server side, then people feel that pain, and start to look at client side for the answer.  Then the pendulum swings the other way and client side is popular.  But then people begin to feel the pain of the cost of client side, and server side starts to look very good, so the pendulum swings back the other way.

So while 5-10 years down the road it may be heavy on the client side, in another 5-10 years it may be heavy on the server side again.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Pretty well stated summation sir.